# Is “what is the mind” is a clause like “A is B”?

Tags: indirect-speech

I have seen some people use the sentence *“what is the mind is being debated widely”* instead of  *“what the mind is is being debated widely”*.

Their reason is that *“what is the mind”* is a clause like *“A is B”*, so it can be used that way.

Is it correct? If so, is the first sentence below as grammatically correct as the second one, which is constructed in a usual form?

> 1. He tries to explain what the mind is.
> 2. He tries to explain what is the mind.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is an error in the last question. The correct sequence of the last two sentences is:1. He tries to explain what is the mind.
2. He tries to explain what the mind is.

Comment: It should be 2. "He tries to explain [what the mind is]." The bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). Unlike main clause interrogatives, these interrogatives do not generally have subject-auxiliary inversion. The meaning can be glossed as "he tries to explain the answer to the question 'What is the mind?' " The same applies to your first example, which should be "[What the mind is] is being debated widely", where the bracketed element is again a subordinate interrogative clause.

Comment: Thank you very much. After reading your answer,  I've done some readings about this clause type and other clause types, and I understand more now. ^^